# POST Object to VB.NET web service via ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, soap

I'm trying to pass a object from .NET MVC to Web Service (VB.NET) suing SOAP.
Passing individual fields works but when I try to pass an object, it throws an error

```
Cannot convert from Project.Models.Table to Project.WebService.Table
```

**REQUIREMENTS**
To pass an Object from MVC to Web Service.

Below is my Web Service code.

**Questions:** Do I need to serialize once I get the object.

```
 <WebMethod()>
    Public Function FormData(ByVal obj As Table)
        Dim sqlconn As New SqlConnection
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
        Try
         Dim formSerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Table))
            Using reader As TextReader = New StringReader(obj)
                data = formSerializer.Deserialize(reader)
            End Using
```

Below is my MVC Controller, I have added the Service Reference.

```
 public ActionResult Submission(Table data)
        {
            Table obj = new Table();
            FormService.WebServiceSoapClient client = new FormService.WebServiceSoapClient();
            obj = client.FormData(data);
            return obj;
         }
```

The **error** is while passing the data object from Controller to Web Service.

The Table model class with all the fields are added in both the projects.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
As per the suggestions of @Panagiotis Kanavos, I tried using AutoMapper. So below is the **working code**. I am able to store values to database. Please do let me know if its correct and secured way. Thanks.

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
public JsonResult PostMethod(Table data)
{
FormService.WebServiceSoapClient client = new FormService.WebServiceSoapClient();
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<Table, Table_WS>(); });
IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
var destination = iMapper.Map<Table, Table_WS>(data);
var result = client.FormData(destination);
```

**WEB SERVICE**

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function FormData(ByVal Obj As Table_WS) As Table_WS

sqlconn.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING
sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconn
sqlconn.Open()
sqlcmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SPR_INSERT"
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", IIf(IsNothing(Obj.NAME), DBNull.Value, Obj.NAME))
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Why are you using a pre-2008 ASMX service at all? And even with that, why make raw HTTP calls instead of creating a SOAP proxy?

Comment: Have to use this 2008 asmx. I am new to this, so trying first to send raw data. Once i succeed doing this, then i shall try the SOAP proxy.

Comment: Even with ASMX, that `Form` isn't a web service at all. For starters, SOAP doesn't work with JSON, SOAP is a *well defined* standard using XML that needs to follow specific standards. .NET and Visual Studio allows you to easily generate XML from classes or parse XML into classes, implementing the necessary standards

Comment: `so trying first to send raw data` don't. You won't succeed. SOAP doesn't deal with raw messages, it works with very specific XML messages. When you added that `WebMethod` attributed you told Visual Studio to generate XML generating and parsing code that accepts a well-formatted XML message, specific namespaces, and an operation endpoint for `Form`,  If you're new to this, don't use ASMX **at all**. It's not just old, it doesn't implement the interoperability standards defined after 2003. If you *really* want to create a SOAP service, you'll have to use WCF

Comment: If you don't need SOAP, use Web API or gRPC instead. If you really need to use SOAP, start with the [Getting Started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial). The code you posted doesn't work at all. Both the client and server side code are wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hello Panagiotis, Thank you for helping me out with my problems. However, I have updated my code based on your inputs. Now I am using SOAP to access the functions of my web service. But I am unable to pass objects, Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You changed the question completely, so now any answers and comments posted before the edit are useless. Not nice. If you have a different question, post a different question. You're still using ASMX which is pointless. Did someone really ask you to create an obsolete service with interoperability problems and no community support? In those specific words? Why do you insist then?

Comment: In any case, the error message is clear. You're using two different `Table` classes in different namespaces. You can't use one object in place of another just because their names are the same. Either use the same object throughout or create a new `Project.WebService.Table` with data from `Project.Models.Table`

Comment: Conversions between one DTO type to another are common. As long as they have similar shape, you can use a library like [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) to convert from one type to another

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you so much for your valuable comments. I really succeed in sending my object to WS. Please do let me know if its secured and correct way of doing it. I have updated my code. You may find the new udpates under UPDATE section. I do apologize for re-framing the above questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're passing that much data, I think you should POST it, not GET it cause you clearly attempt to send something, not retrieve.
Secondly - I don't know VB.NET, but I assume '' stands for comment so your code will always try to deserialize data as XML. You could try passing parameter to inform your web method which serialization method is used. Again - I'm not sure how it's done in VB.NET.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot convert between the 2 tables.
Public Function FormData(ByVal obj As Table) is expecting Project.WebService.Table and you are passing in Project.Models.Table. I think that is the correct order.
You need to pass into client.FormData a Project.WebService.Table.
You will have to convert your Project.Models.Table to a Project.WebService.Table

Something like this, should work.

```
        public ActionResult Submission(Table data)
        {
            var client = new FormService.WebService1();
            var table = new FormService.Table();
            table.FirstName = data.FirstName;
            table.LastName = data.LastName;
            var obj = client.FormData(table);

            data.FirstName = obj.FirstName;
            data.LastName = obj.LastName;
            ...
        }
```

The only way to do this with serialization would to use JSON and pass it as a string to the web method, at that point you could convert into any class you want.

Comment: `only way to do this with serialization would to use JSON...` here are many ways to convert but this is definitely not one. It converts a lazy and slow method (convert through serialization) with a major design bug (passing raw strings to a web service instead of using a proper schema).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I tried to map objects using **AutoMapper** and it worked as expected.